# Purchase & Restore functionality

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

In my app, I implement the in-app purchase.

**Functionality**

I check the no of records inserted in DB. If it is grater than 5 than make the in-app purchase for insert more records.

**My code for that**

```
//condition for checking records & if already purchase
if (([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"std_inapp"]==5)&&(![[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]valueForKey:@"IN_APP_PURCHASE"]isEqualToString:@"YES"])) {


 if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) {

productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:kInAppPurchaseProUpgradeProductId]];
                productsRequest.delegate = self ;
                [productsRequest start];
}
}
```

**QUESTION**

But when the user will delete the app & install it again how can i restore the in-app purchase without interacting with any extra button??

**Where should i put the code/condition for restore purchase?**

Thank you,

Help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What has records in the db got to do with in app purchase? But to answer your question - according to Apple guidelines, you *need* to give a button for restoring non-consumable purchases.

Answer (score 0):

You can put restore button in same screen in which you have Buy button. OR you can put it in same initial screen. When you go to restore for any product, you will get all product identifier which you have purchased in Restoredidfinish method. So, you can take necessary steps after as you are taking in purchasedidifinish method.